# Search two dimensional array that returned true to a given method using O(n) time complexity there's a catch

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, search, time-complexity

so I'm in need of a java method that receives a two dimensional integer array and an integer and finds the integer within the array. If found, would return true; false otherwise. **But with time complexity of O(n)**

```
public static boolean findValTest(int[][] m, int val)
```

So here's the catch, we also know that the two dimensional array that was passed into our method returned true to the following method:

```
  public static boolean test(int [][] m)
{
 int n=m.length;
 for(int r=0; r<(n-1); r++)
    for (int c=0; c<n; c++)
       for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
          if(m[r][c] > m[r+1][i]) return false;
return true;
}
```

the method test checks if a value in a line is smaller than all of the values in the following line. If true it returns true; False otherwise.

here is an example for an array that **passed the method test**:

```
int [][] arr = new int [][] {
                { 0,   2,    1,    2,   0,  5,   5,   5,  },
                { 21,  21,   7,    7,   7,  21,  21,  21 ,},
                { 21,  21,  21,   21,  21,  21,  21 , 21, },
                { 21,  21,  23 ,  42,  41,  23,  21,  21, },
                { 60  ,56,  57,   58,  53,  52,  47,  51 ,},
                { 61,  65,  70 ,  72,  73,  78,  82,  98 ,},
                { 112, 121, 112, 134, 123, 100,  98,  111,},
                { 136, 136, 136, 134, 147, 150,  154, 134,},
            };
```

adding the API documentation of the method findValTest

```
/**
     * Checks if a given value exists in a given array; While it is known that given the method test returns true for the given array
     * @param m the array to check
     * @param val the value to find
     * @return true if val is found in the array; false otherwise.
     * @timeComplexity O(n) n- the array's (m) length
     * @spaceComplexity O(1)
     */
```

The catch here is to find an algorithm with a time complexity of O(n) that could find the value based on what we know from the method test.

Here is my method, it doesn't work thou...

```
public static boolean findValTest(int[][] m, int val) {
        int index = 0;
        while(index < m.length) {
            if(m[index][0] < val)
                index++;
            else
                break;
        }

        for(int index2 = 0; index2 < m[0].length; index2++) {
            if(m[index][index2] == val)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I'm pretty sure that its not even O(n) but O(n^2)...

Comment: So every column is sorted, right? Then do a binary search on an arbitrary column, finding the closest value `<=` the value to be found. Then do a linear search in that row. That will work in `O(log n) + O(n) = O(n)`. Or did I miss anything?

Comment: sebrockm , mmm no i think that will do. I'll go write it, thanks!

Comment: @sebrockm I don't think it will. Say, we are looking for `5`, and after sort you can see `4` and `6`. `5` can be in either of the two rows.

Comment: @ShadowOverLoad The problem with your solution is that the number can be in either of two rows. Let's say that you are looking for `41` - your first loop will choose `index = 4` (line starting with `60`), but `41` is in the previous row. However, if you are searching for `53`, your method correctly returns `true`.

Comment: @sebrockm , It is still not working I've updated my code in this post

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak thanks for the respond i just changed it

Comment: @ShadowOverLoad don't constantly change the original code you posted - by doing so, you make all comments and answers irrelevant, because they refer to the code that is no longer there.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak yoi are absolutely right! Then looking in these two rows may be fine. Still `O(n)`

Comment: It is very important for you to understand the property of the code given in test , it states that a[r][X] > a[i][j]  for all i > r. So not just all columns are sorted if you create a sub array from r,x it will mean A[r][X] will be the smallest value in the array.  Do binary search on diagonals to come up with a smaller squares.

Comment: So are we facing a group of students all "individually" having their homework solved by others? :D

Comment: @sebrockm I actually tried and couldn't find that topic XD its really hard so don't blame us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smth. like that. In case of *Every number at row `i` is equals or smaller then every number on row `i+1`*, than you can check only first element in each row to define a row, where required value could be. Element in unsorted row can be found only with full scan.

This algorithm have to *scan 2 full rows* only, which is ***O(n)* where *n - number of rows***.

```
public static boolean findValTest(int[][] m, int val) {
    for (int row = 0; row < m.length; row++) {
        if (m[row][0] <= val && row != m.length - 1)
            continue;

        int r = row;

        while (r >= row - 1 && r >= 0) {
            for (int col = 0; col < m[r].length; col++)
                if (m[r][col] == val)
                    return true;

            r--;
        }

        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Test cases:

```
System.out.println(findValTest(arr3, -1)); // false
System.out.println(findValTest(arr3, 5)); // true
System.out.println(findValTest(arr3, 7)); // true
System.out.println(findValTest(arr3, 55)); // false
System.out.println(findValTest(arr3, 47)); // true
System.out.println(findValTest(arr3, 147)); // true
System.out.println(findValTest(arr3, 200)); // false
System.out.println(findValTest(new int[][] { { 3, 4, 5 } }, 4));   // true
```

Comment: @ShadowOverLoad no

Comment: Yes, i see it now! Thank you, your solution is very smart!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your solution is that the number can be in either of two rows. Let's say that you are looking for `41` - your first loop will choose `index = 4` (line starting with 60), but `41` is in the previous row. However, if you are searching for `53`, your method correctly returns true.

```
public static boolean findValTest(int[][] array, int val) {
    int chosenRow = 0;
    while (chosenRow < array.length) {
        if (array[chosenRow][0] < val) {
            chosenRow++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int row = min(chosenRow, array[0].length - 1); row >= max(chosenRow - 1, 0); row--) { // max 2 iterations - chosen row, and row before
        for (int col = 0; col < array[0].length; col++) {
            if (array[row][col] == val) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

We need to do `min`, as `chosenRow` can exceed the array size, when e.g. looking for 147. And we need to check `max`, in case `chosenRow` is 0, when e.g. looking for 0.

It might be prettier to actually copy-paste the inner loop and put both of them under if-statements, rather than doing an outer loop.

Comment: I have just updated my solution, still not working

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
 at Ex14.findValTest(Ex14.java:80)
 at Test14.main(Test14.java:95)
while I am looking for the number 136

Comment: yes I am passing it the array in the example and the numbers: 0 , 1 , 2 , 5 , 7 , 21 , 23 , 41 , 42 , 47 , 51 , 52 , 53 , 56 , 57 , 58 , 
60 , 61 , 65 , 70 , 72 , 73 , 78 , 82 , 98 , 100 , 111 , 112 , 121 , 123 , 134 , 136 , 147 , 
150 , 154 to find, it sends this after 134: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
 at Ex14.findValTest(Ex14.java:64)
 at Test14.main(Test14.java:95)